# Vue-CLI Webpack how do you import vue-shopify-products library?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-shopify-products) says like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vue-shopify-products.js"></script>
```

And then before you initialize vue, you do this:

```
 Vue.use(ShopifyProducts);
```

What do you do if you use [vue-cli webpack template?](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli)

My main.js file looks like this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import * as shopifyProducts from 'vue-shopify-products'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(shopifyProducts)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',

  created: function () {
    d3.csv('/static/data/csv-files/bicycles.csv', (data) => {
      let products = this.$formatProducts(data)
      console.log(products)
    })
  }
})
```

This doesn't work as I get the error 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.$formatProducts is not a function'. What is the correct way to include Vue-Shopify-Products and reference the $formatProducts function?

Comment: The `vue-shopify-products` package is not importable because it doesn't export anything. In fact, it only sets a local variable with `const` (when it probably meant to use `var`), so the script effectively does nothing useful. You should probably file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an npm package installed as a dependency, you should import it this way,

`import defaultExport from "module-name";`

so this should work:

```
import ShopifyProducts from "vue-shopify-products";
Vue.use(ShopifyProducts);
```

After that you can get rid of the script reference of the module.

**Edit 1:**

I don't think is going to work since the [module](https://github.com/mikestreety/vue-shopify-products/blob/master/src/vue-shopify-products.js) you are trying to use as a Vue plugin do not follow the conventions especified on the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html).

Comment: Thank you, you were correct I had to fork the project and amend it to meet Vue's plugin standards.